# parsing from String to Float returns float value with question marks in it

Tags: android

So as the title says i am trying to parse a string value into a float value but i am getting a number format exception like this ***Invalid float: "3??.??5??2"*** the actual number is 3.52. Oh and im doing it all in a Fragment which causes me troubles. Im also not using any DecimalFormats on this Float value when im saving it to a file. So what am i doing wrong? :(
The way i am reading/writing a file is this:

```
file = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "userZinsenArray.txt");

 save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String outputString = "";
            try {

                if (!file.exists())
                    file.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("file exists:" + file.exists());
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                DataOutputStream ps = new DataOutputStream(stream);
                for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.prozentenArray.size(); i++) {
                    outputString+=(""+MainActivity.prozentenArray.get(i));
                    outputString+="\n";
                }
                ps.writeChars(outputString);
                ps.close();
                stream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             String line=null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);
                    while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        MainActivity.prozentenArray.add(Float.parseFloat(line));                            
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                   System.out.println("numberFormatException: "+e.getMessage());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("other exp: "+e.getMessage());
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: well, you are reading from some file, check if the file contains a line with `3??.??5??2`

Comment: the file itself shows no question marks or they are not displayable. i just checked my InputStreamReader with input.getEncoding() and it shows me UTF8 every time

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: or use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Comment: changing my encoding doesn't help my InputStreamReader input already uses UTF8 (checked that with input.getEncoding())